# How is the 'cookie' global object supposed to work on xPages?

Tags: xpages

How is the 'cookie' global object supposed to work on xPages? It is a map, so I can check the cookie existence easily, but how to create a new cookie? Using cookie.name="value" raises an error because, as supposed, the cookie must be some object with params like expiration etc. But what kind of the object it is? I can't find any suitable documentation for this or I miss something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

cookie object represents a map of cookie values of the **request** instance. So you cannot use it because 'setting cookie' means 'adding cookie to the response'.

So, as the article suggests, you have to use response object.

```
var response = facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse(); 
var userCookie = new javax.servlet.http.Cookie("name", "value"); 
userCookie.setMaxAge(60*60*24*365*10); // set age in seconds...
userCookie.setPath("/"); // cookie will be valid under this path
response.addCookie(userCookie);
```

Answer (score 2):

I can not give an answer on the cookie global object, but the following article shows how to manage cookies in XPages using the javax.servlet.http.Cookie class:

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/cookie-management.html

Maybe the cookie global object expects an object of type javax.servlet.http.Cookie?

Comment: I have found this article already but it doesnt work with 'cookie' global object. It raises following error: Script interpreter error, line=13, col=8: Error calling method 'put(string, javax.servlet.http.Cookie)' on java class 'com.sun.faces.context.RequestCookieMap' ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using resources and defining meta tag as Set-Cookie?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56763401 -- this method is no longer supported.