# Setting a Cookie using only HTML5

Tags: html, cookies

I found this article where it explains how to [set a cookie using only HTML](https://www.willmaster.com/library/cookies/setting-a-cookie-using-only-html.php).

He use `http-equiv` attribute on the `<meta>` in the `<head>` of an HTML document:

```
<meta http-equiv="set-cookie" content="___________">
```

Now I have read about [HTML < meta> http-equiv Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp) but 
I could not understand how to use it for set a cookie.

Someone can explain to me if you can use this method for set cookie or that guide is just a joke?
I tried this but `HolidayGlaze` cookie has not been saved.

```
<meta http-equiv="set-cookie" content="HolidayGlaze=Good%20yummies; expires=Sat, 25-Nov-2023 12:00:00 GMT; domain=.example.com; path=/; secure; httponly;">
```

P.S. I read also about *Differences Between HTML 4.01 and HTML5* syntax so my question is about the correct syntax for HTML5.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You used to be able to set cookies using a meta tag, however browsers are moving away from that in favour of [HTTP headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie), or [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

If you try to set a cookie using meta tags in Chrome, you will get a warning and/or error (depending on your version). The feature has been deprecated in M63, and completely removed in M65.

> [Deprecation] Setting cookies via `<meta http-equiv='Set-Cookie' ...>` no longer works, as of M65. Consider switching to  `document.cookie = ...`, or to `Set-Cookie` HTTP headers instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6170540112871424 for more details.

> Blocked setting the `Example cookie; path=/; expires=Friday, 24-Mar-18 10:00:00 GMT` cookie from a `<meta>` tag.

I would imagine that other browsers also have this feature deprecated/removed, or will follow suit shortly with chrome.

You can read more about the deprecation of this feature here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=767813

Answer (score 0):

Don't set cookies in HTML with meta http-equiv="set-cookie". It's outdated and has no effect in modern browsers that follow the current HTML5 standard (it's non-conforming in HTML5).